# How to play multi-channel sound (from PC) on music center

Tags: audio, input, media-center, soldering

Music center have 5 speakers and 1 subwoofer. But has only 2-ch AUX IN (means sound from PC plays only on two speakers).

There is a way to play sound from PC on 5 speakers? Maybe I can enable converting from 2ch to 5ch? When play audio CD there is a option, that play 2ch sound on 5 speakers. Can I set this option for AUX?
Or may be a way to solder multi-channel input?

Music center model: LG LM-KW6530X

Comment: What other inputs do you have? Do you have a yellow co-axial digital in?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no such. Only one input - this is AUX. And thought that may be there is hidden input? (for example, not soldered to internal board).